# display HTML page after loading complete

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there a way to force the browser to display a page only after all of the page's contents are completely loaded (such as images, scripts, css, etc)?

Comment: I like being able to start reading a page before it has fully loaded, especially if I'm on a slow connection.

Comment: Probably not to the extent you're suggesting (including scripts), and I think this smells of bad design. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @tdammers why would it be a bad design? e.g. if the page is localized based on <html lang="en"> and the language gets changed in the JS while loading according to the browsers language, etc. then you see for a few ms the whole text in english and then it changes to the defined language. Another example having placeholders in textes that you must replace in JS, the same effect.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is putting a `div` with the following CSS in the body:

```
#hideAll
 {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px; 
   right: 0px; 
   top: 0px; 
   bottom: 0px; 
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 99; /* Higher than anything else in the document */

 }
```

(Note that `position: fixed` won't work in IE6 - I know of no sure-fire way of doing this in that browser)

Add the DIV like so (directly after the opening `body` tag):

```
<div style="display: none" id="hideAll">&nbsp;</div>
```

show the DIV directly after :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "block";
 </script>
```

and hide it `onload`:

```
 window.onload = function() 
  { document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "none"; }
```

or using jQuery

```
 $(window).load(function() {  document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "none"; });
```

this approach has the advantage that it will also work for clients who have JavaScript turned off. It *shouldn't* cause any flickering or other side-effects, but not having tested it, I can't entirely guarantee it for every browser out there.

Comment: since you are calling it by id, fix `.hideAll` to `#hideAll`

Comment: personally I think its time to cut-off ie6 support anyways.. such a hassle to work around

Comment: It almost works for my case. I try to hide all html elements in a dojo test application, but it still display for a second a not yet formatted html element. But still, it still hold after all elements completed the loading process

Comment: Thank you very much Pekka. How do I name this page correctly ? "loading page" , "intro screen" ? or what ?

Comment: position: fixed; blocks scrolling. It is not necessary even.

Answer (score 8):

put an overlay on the page

```
#loading-mask {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

and then delete that element in a `window.onload` handler or, hide it

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('loading-mask').style.display='none';
}
```

Of course you should use your javascript library (jquery,prototype..) specific onload handler if you are using a library.

Comment: Also, this never displays the page at all if javascript is disabled... See @Pekka웃's answer for something slightly safer.

Comment: @Tao you can use modernizer for figuring out if brower is IE6 or javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

Hide the body initially, and then show it with jQuery after it has loaded.

```
body {
    display: none;
}

$(function () {
    $('body').show();
}); // end ready
```

Also, it would be best to have `$('body').show();` as the last line in your last and main .js file.

Answer (score 5):

you can also go for this.... this will only show the HTML section once javascript has loaded.

```
<!-- Adds the hidden style and removes it when javascript has loaded -->
<style type="text/css">
    .hideAll  {
        visibility:hidden;
     }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#tabs").removeClass("hideAll");
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs" class="hideAll">
   ##Content##
</div>
```

Comment: ` $(window).on("load", function() {  ` in case you are using jquery 3.

Answer (score 0):

try using javascript for this!
Seems like its the best and easiest way to do this.
You'll get inbuilt funcn to execute a html code only after HTML page loads completely.

or else you may use state based programming where an event occurs at a particular state of the browser..