# How to mask everything when a popupbox is displayed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a popup window and below is my script.

```
         var action="generateCertificate";
         var url=contextPath +"/MyPage/MyPage.do?actionToPerform="+action;
         var myWindow=window.open(url,"","width=500,height=500");
```

And the script is successfully creating a popup window.

now my issue is when i click on the background of my page the popupbox is getting hided.

how to mask the background when popupbox is fired.

Plz help me.

Comment: Have you thought about using a dialog box with an iframe in it, such as with Bootstrap?

Comment: You may want to check jQuery UI and its modal dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: it is not possible using javascript?

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma jQuery **is** JavaScript, it's just making writing it much easier as other people already wrote it for you. For this purpose jQuery is very common choice, can't see any reason why not use it. Anyway, you might take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630230/javascript-modal-popup), if you didn't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery BlockUI Plugin :  [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to make a popup window modal. As the name itself suggests that it is a separate window.

If you want, you can use `showModalDialog()` in Javascript. The dialog allows you to include a jsp or html page inside

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog

Also as suggested by others above, you can go for jQuery.