# how to do any particular actiona or acitivity at the end of html page loading

Tags: javascript, html, validation, pageload

Is there a way to find out whether the HTML page has completed loading?,

I have to do some combo box loading at the end of HTML page loading. Please help me to do this.

UPDATE :

```
my question is how to load some values after page is completely loaded not only the images,css, etc but also all the controls in it, like some text boxes may have values from the server and so on.
```

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [display HTML page after loading complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629762/display-html-page-after-loading-complete)

Comment: this might help 
if (document.readyState === "complete") { init(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event handler in JavaScript.

Comment: yes this absolutely works to implementation please check http://www.gee.web.id/2016/11/how-to-execute-javascript-when-page-has.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yet?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      // put stuff into combo boxes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in case you are using jQuery, use the classic:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // combo box loading
});
```

I guess it will be also easier to reference the combo boxes if you use jQuery