# Page load before display - SEO Best practice

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

There are many ways **to display a page only when content is loaded**, but **what is the best way regarding SEO ?**

Contents are : pictures, css, js, etc.

*Is Google bot getting smart enough to not-index pages that have tricks like those ?*

> - CSS `<body> display none`.
> - Javascript  add `display none`, on_event_i_am_ready , remove `display none`.
> - `<body> margin -20000px`.
> - Full white div `z-index` > body  `z-index`.
> - body `height & width` to `0px` with `overflow: hidden;`
> - And much more solutions...
>
> Stackoverflow: [Solution two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded), [Solution one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629762/display-html-page-after-loading-complete), etc..

Comment: What's your use case for wanting to do this? For something like Gmail, it makes sense to preload then switch over to the full web app. But in general it's probably best to find a way to give the user something to look at or do while the rest of the page loads. If they're forced to wait for _every_ resource to load (which could take a long time!!) they may not stick around.

Comment: Well, i won't wait for "all" the ressources to be loaded before displaying the page. But all the key ressources that are used on that page. So the user don't see any "changing" things on the page; he don't see a loading page, but a full loaded page -Looks more professional- Have a look at facebook, they are doing that as well.

Comment: In order to make a meaninful suggestion, it would help to know what types of resources you are wanting to load before page display. Best techniques for this vary for Javascript, images, etc.

Comment: I just looked at facebook. Everything loaded in a linear fashion. There was no artifical delays before displaying anything. Artificial delays suck. If the page loads slowly enough for it to matter, then you should look to optimise the page. Remove extraneous content from it, use fewer, lighter images, etc.

Comment: "More professional" is certainly debatable. I find preloaders childish and unprofessional. The web works the way it works and everybody is used to it. There's no problem worth fixing here. The only thing you want to avoid are FOUCs and content that jumps around erratically as images are loaded in, both of which are avoidable without preloaders.

Comment: Consider that depending on your setup, content and use of third party resources, there may be transient periods when one or more page items does not load - and that (where-ever possible) this should not prevent users from accessing the remainder of your content. Consider also the implications for users with low bandwidth - either on mobile, or overseas where high speed connections may not be available. Don't make the mistake of assuming your experience of the site is the same as that of all your users. I agree with the other posters, this isn't a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for sure is **don't do it**. If you care about SEO, just **optimize your page to work fast and do not need some pre-load message**. Avoid do any (black) magic.

Just a very few cases could be a good idea use these types of message, and in general, are just for apps that already do not are search friendly, like your email client. Is better use your time to improve your page load than wast even more bytes on it.